# How to remove character at the end of every line in file. Liquibase Java SQL

Tags: java, mysql, csv, liquibase

I have a txt file which goes like that:

```
id;name;secondName;
1;Jordan;Smith;
2;Michael;Jackson;
3;David;Park;
...
```

I have to load this data to a SQL DataBase using liquibase but I cant do it because of ";" charackter at the end of every line. How to remove this?

I have something like that by far :

```
<changeSet id="3" author="me">
    <createTable tableName="names">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" >
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="secondName" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="4" author="me">
    <loadData
            file="names.txt"
            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
            schemaName="test"
            separator=";"
            tableName="names">
        <column header="id" name="id" type="bigint"/>
        <column header="name" name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column header="secondName" name="secondName" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Or add a dummy column.

Comment: How should it look like?

Comment: Sorry, I meant add a collumn to the table, that will get filled by the CSV import with an empty string.

Comment: It works but I have to drop this column later. Thanks anyway